# theme_preprocess_node not working inside of a view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, theming

I'm trying to add a variable to the $classes array on a node, but it's not adding it while the node is in a view.

```
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {
  // Add the terms to the body classes for my_node_type'.

  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    if ($node->type == 'my_node_type') {

  // Return an array of taxonomy term ID's.
  $termids = field_get_items('node', $node, 'my_field_name');

  // Load all the terms to get the name and vocab.
  foreach ($termids as $termid) {
    $terms[] = taxonomy_term_load($termid['tid']);
  }

  // Assign the taxonomy values.
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $class = strtolower(drupal_clean_css_identifier($term->name));
    $vocabulary = drupal_clean_css_identifier($term->vocabulary_machine_name);
    $vars['classes_array'][] = $class;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I added a

```
<?php dpm($classes); ?>
```

on my node.tpl.php I'm able to see the particular field being added to the classes array in my `<div class="my_field_name">`. But when it's in a view, the class isn't applied which makes me think that the preprocess_node isn't being called properly. Any suggestions for what I should do or anything I'm missing that's preventing the hook_preprocess_node from being called properly? I've tried placing it into my theme's template.php instead of in the custom module I'm using but neither work.

**ANSWER NINJA EDIT** (can't post one for another 8 hours)

I was able to finally get it to call the classes properly. Appears that these conditions were not being met in the view:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    if ($node->type == 'my_node_type') {
```

so I removed that line and instead replaced it with

```
$node = $vars['node'];
```

Removed the code from my custom module and placed it in my custom theme's template.php o the function now looks like this

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {
  // Add the terms to the body classes for MY_NODE_TYPE'.
  $node = $vars['node'];

  // Return an array of taxonomy term ID's.
  $termids = field_get_items('node', $node, 'MY_FIELD_NAME');

  // Load all the terms to get the name and vocab.
  foreach ($termids as $termid) {
    $terms[] = taxonomy_term_load($termid['tid']);
  }

  // Assign the taxonomy values.
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $class = strtolower(drupal_clean_css_identifier($term->name));
    $vocabulary = drupal_clean_css_identifier($term->vocabulary_machine_name);
    $vars['classes_array'][] = $class;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$node = menu_get_object()` works only when the page you are seeing has a URL that is similar to node/12, or node/12/view. When you are watching a view, its URL is probably different.

That code is also not necessary, as [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) already initializes `$variables['node']` with the node object.

```
$variables['node'] = $variables['elements']['#node'];
$node = $variables['node'];
```

If you want to check if the node is being viewed in its own page, you can use the following code.

```
if ($variables['page']) {
  // The node is shown in its own page.
}
else {
  // The node is shown together other nodes.
}
```

`$variable['page']` is a variable set by `template_preprocess_node()`.

As side note, this is the code used by [views_plugin_row_node_view::render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!node!views_plugin_row_node_view.inc/function/views_plugin_row_node_view%3a%3arender/7) to render a node.

```
function render($row) {
  if (isset($this->nodes[$row->{$this->field_alias}])) {
    $node = $this->nodes[$row->{$this->field_alias}];
    $node->view = $this->view;
    $build = node_view($node, $this->options['view_mode']);

    return drupal_render($build);
  }
}
```

[node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7) is the function that calls the `theme_node()` theme function, causing preprocess/process functions to be called.